# Terminologies in Acoustic-phonetic Vowel classifier

Tags: terminology, vowels, speech-recognition

An acoustic-phonetic vowel classifier uses a tree based classification.

Consider F1 and F2 as formant frequencies. At it's first step, it checks for **COMPACT/DIFFUSE** (High F1/Low F1). At the second, it checks for **ACUTE/GRAVE** (High F2/Low F2). Next check is, **TENSE/LAX** (long or short). Most of the vowels are identified by this step itself.

Final step (if required) checks for **FLAT/PLAIN** (F1+F2>T / F1+F2<T). The threshold is experimentally found.

How do you explain the name-reason for **terminologies** based on the conditions shown in parenthesis?

Comment: it's hard for me to understand what the question here is. What do you mean by name-reason and terminologies?

Comment: @Tristan I meant, is it possible to explain why you call it "Compact" or "Diffuse" based on high or low F1?

Answer (score 0):

Binary classifications like compact/diffuse, acute/grave and tense/lax go back quite some way in the history of phonology, to Roman Jakobson, Morris Halle's/Noam Chomsky's *Sound Pattern of English* etc.
Although they have been and still are widely used, they do not have universally accepted acoustic or articulatory phonetic definitions – just one example: it is debatable whether what many phonologists call the tense/lax distinction should acoustically be based mainly on duration differences (as you mention) or on F1/F2 variation (tense vowels being more peripheral than lax ones) or on a certain combination of these, and perhaps additional, cues.

You seem to be looking for a 1:1 relationship of historically developed phonological terms and acoustic-phonetic measures; I am afraid you will not easily find such a relationship.

Comment: Is it really debatable that duration is a good measure for vowel tenseness, though? It may work fairly well for standard British and American English, but tenseness and length are fundamentally different phonetic concepts, and there are many languages where the two are orthogonal, with both short tense and long lax vowels (Icelandic, for example, or even just many forms of Scottish English).

Comment: What does "more peripheral" mean here?

Comment: More "peripheral" means farther away from the center of the F1/F2 vowel chart, corresponding, in articulatory terms, to the tongue's highest point's position being further away from the center of the oral cavity.